# How to select records with two columns matching values in one table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating one request form online, where employee generate request in system but his/her boss only able to view those employee's request who are working under him.

For ex: In an organization there are various employees are working under 1 boss.

```
---------------------
|EmpNo   |BossNo    |
---------------------
|011     |001       |
|012     |001       |
|013     |001       |
|014     |002       |
---------------------
```

Here in above table scenario if an employee(012) will generate any request then only boss(001) is able to view that request no one else, same as employee(014) will generate any request then only boss(002) is able to view that request and accept it.

I want to create SQL Query for this..But I am fail to create query for this.
Here below is the query

```
select e1.empno, e1.bossno
  from employeedetails as e1
  inner join employeedetails as e2
    on e1.empno= e2.empno
   and e1.bossno= e2.bossno
  group by e1.empno, e1.bossno
  order by e1.empno, e1.bossno
```

Comment: Do you use any ORM?

Comment: Please post the schema of `Request` table.

Comment: Do you want SQL query to achieve your goal?

Comment: What is the question

Comment: @er-sho Yes, because i don't have any idea how can i achieve this..!

Comment: @dmegha, please show your attempt to create sql query?

Comment: use RECURSIVE CTE query to achieve this

Comment: @er-sho I updated question with query

Comment: @mrR Is there any example?

Comment: @dmegha my mistake if you only need 1 level then just join it with from employeedetails as e1
  inner join employeedetails as e2
    on e1.bossno= e2.empno where e1.bossno='001' - should show only boss 001 employees requests

Comment: @dmegha, This is redundant to make inner join on same table. and this will increase your complexity of query. so try this simple query like => `SELECT bossno FROM employeedetails WHERE empno = 014` so this will only gives your boss 002

Comment: @dmegha, Or if you want only one `boss 002` for `emp 014` then you can use query like => `SELECT DISTINCT(bossno) FROM employeedetails WHERE empno = 014`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT request.Info, request.empno, empDetails.EmployeeName
FROM requestTable as Request
    INNER JOIN employeedetails AS empDetails ON Request.empno = empDetails.empno
WHERE empDetails.bossno = @IdOfLoggedInEmployee
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, both table retrieve same values then use join as `e1.empno= e2.empno and e1.bossno= e2.bossno`

I think so:

```
select e1AsBoss.empno as idBoss , e2AsEmployer.empno as idEmployer
  from employeedetails as e1AsBoss
  inner join employeedetails as e2AsEmployer
    on e1AsBoss.empno= e2AsEmployer.bossno
  group by e1AsBoss.empno, e2AsEmployer.empno
  order by e1AsBoss.empno, e2AsEmployer.empno
```